# different scope when using class/constructor vs. variable methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, constructor, scope

I've got a script that parses a particular object property for keywords, then appends those keywords and another property to the object. The new property values are printed to the document for error checking.

```
    var chemistry = {
     field: "chemistry",
     keywords: [
         "atom",
         "proton",
         "electron",
         "wavefunction",
         "neutron",
         "catalyst"],
     filter: function( title ) {
             var i;
             for( i = 0 ; i < title.split( " " ).length; i++ )  {
             var title_part = title.toLowerCase().split( " " )[ i ];
             var j;                    
                for( j = 0 ; j < this.keywords.length; j++ ) {
                    if ( this.keywords[ j ] == title_part && library[ 0 ].keywords.indexOf( this.keywords[ j ] ) == -1 ) {
                        library[ 0 ].keywords.push( this.keywords[ j ] );
                        if ( library[ 0 ].field.indexOf( this.field ) == -1 ) {
                            library[ 0 ].field.push( this.field );
                         };
                     };
                 };
             };
         }
   };

chemistry.filter( library[0].title );

document.writeln( "KEYWORDS: " + library[0].keywords );
document.writeln( "FIELD: " + library[0].field );
```

This works fine, but I'm trying to create a class which constructs a new object as above. Here's the code I'm using

```
"use strict"         
class Discipline {
     constructor(field, keyword) {
         this.field = field;
         this.keywords = keyword;
         this.filter =  function( title ) {
             var i;
             for( i = 0 ; i < title.split( " " ).length; i++ )  {
             var title_part = title.toLowerCase().split( " " )[ i ];
             var j;                    
                for( j = 0 ; j < this.keywords.length; j++ ) {
                    if ( this.keywords[ j ] == title_part && library[ 0 ].keywords.indexOf( this.keywords[ j ] ) == -1 ) {
                        library[ 0 ].keywords.push( this.keywords[ j ] );
                        if ( library[ 0 ].field.indexOf( this.field ) == -1 ) {
                            library[ 0 ].field.push( this.field );
                         };
                     };
                 };
             };
         }
     }
 };

 var chemistry = new Discipline("chemistry", "electron");
 chemistry.filter( library[0].title );

 document.writeln( "KEYWORDS: " + library[0].keywords );
 document.writeln( "FIELD: " + library[0].field );
```

The filter doesn't seem to output anything and I just see "KEYWORDS: FIELD: " in the document. What's confusing is if I check library[0].field and library[0].keywords using document.writeln() I get the expected values.

I'm wondering if the scope of "this." changes when I use the class constructor. Or is something else going on?

As an aside, if anyone knows a good way to pass an array as the keywords parameter, that'd be much appreciated. Right now I'm passing a spaced string and splitting it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the scope of `this` is changing. You can do something like this though:

```
var that = this;
```

and then use `that.keywords` wherever it's needed. So in your code, like this:

```
class Discipline {
     constructor(field, keyword) {
         var that = this;
         that.field = field;
         that.keywords = keyword;
         that.filter =  function( title ) {
             var i;
             for( i = 0 ; i < title.split( " " ).length; i++ )  {
             var title_part = title.toLowerCase().split( " " )[ i ];
             var j;                    
                for( j = 0 ; j < that.keywords.length; j++ ) {
                    if ( that.keywords[ j ] == title_part && library[ 0 ].keywords.indexOf( this.keywords[ j ] ) == -1 ) {
                        library[ 0 ].keywords.push( that.keywords[ j ] );
                        if ( library[ 0 ].field.indexOf( that.field ) == -1 ) {
                            library[ 0 ].field.push( that.field );
                         };
                     };
                 };
             };
         }
     }
 };
```

Comment: So when `var chemistry = new Discipline("chemistry", "electron");` runs, what is this. referring to?

Comment: Inside the `constructor(field, keyword) {}` part, `this` refers to that function. Then when you go into `that.filter = function(title) {}` then `this` is now referring to that new function that you're inside.

Comment: I updated the code, but I'm still not getting the expected result https://jsfiddle.net/jo3ghoLm/